# Longest Simple Path

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computer-science, graph-theory, theory

So, I understand the problem of finding the longest simple path in a graph is NP-hard, since you could then easily solve the Hamiltonian circuit problem by setting edge weights to 1 and seeing if the length of the longest simple path equals the number of edges.

My question is: What kind of path would you get if you took a graph, found the maximum edge weight, `m`, replaced each edge weight `w` with `m - w`, and ran a standard shortest path algorithm on that? It's clearly not the longest simple path, since if it were, then NP = P, and I think the proof for something like that would be a bit more complicated =P.

Comment: Here's a hint: if you find a path of length L in the new graph, and it contains k edges, what is the length of the corresponding path in the old graph?

Comment: It'd be "mk - [sum(weight(i)) for each i in the path]"... I think I need another hint

Comment: What do you mean by "what kind of path"?
I don't think it has any special significance.

Comment: @v3: I think that's the right answer. It won't be the longest simple path or the shortest path of anything, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/317805/path2.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/317805/path2.jpg)

The graph above is transformed to below using your algorithm.

The Longest path is the red line in the above graph.And depending on how ties are broken and algorithm you use, the shortest path in the transformed graph could be the blue line or the red line. So transforming graph edge weights using the constant that you mentioned yields no significant results. This is why you cannot find the longest path using the shortest path algorithms no matter how clever you are. A simpler transformation could be to negate all the edge weights and run the algorithm. I dont know if I have answered your question but as far as the path property goes the transformed graph doesnt have any useful information regarding the distance.

However this particular transformation is useful in other areas. For example you could force the algorithm to select a particular edge weight in bipatrite matching if you have more than one constraint by adding a huge constant.

- Edit: I have been told to add this statement: The above graph is not just about the physical distance. They need not hold the triangle inequality. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems the pic you attached does not work now. Maybe you removed it from your dropbox?

Comment: Damn I really wanted to see the pic

Answer (score 2):

If you could solve shortest path problems with negative weights you would find a longest path, the two are equivalent, this could be done by putting a weight of -w instead of w

The standard algorithm for negative weights is the [Bellman-Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm) algorithm. However the algorithm will not work if there is a cycle in the graph such that the sum of edges is negative. In the graph that you create, all such cycles have negative sum weights and so the algorithm won't work. Unless of course you have no cycles, in which case you have a tree (or a forest) and the problem is solvable via dynamic programming.

If we replace a weight of w by m-w, which guarantees that all weights will be positive, then the shortest path can be found via standard algorithms. If the shortest path P in this graph has k edges then the length is k*m-w(P) where w(P) is the length of the path with the original weights. This path is not necessarily the longest one, however, of all paths with k edges, P is the longest one.

Comment: Ah, I set the new weight to `m-w`, not `-w`. The smallest weight will be 0.

Comment: "Of all paths of length k, P is the longest one." - Wouldn't all paths of length k have equal length?

Comment: I was using "length" in two senses, the number of edges and the sum of the weights. I've clarified this in the edit.